# How to get Exception reason/cause in external package

Tags: java, android, exception

The following line of code throws an Exception:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);    // actual HTTP request
```

I am able to catch it and print:

```
Log.e(TAG0, "Exception " + e.getMessage());
```

Which puts into LogCat:

> 03-03 14:52:11.965:
>   ERROR/TestHttpGet(786): Exception
>   www.google.com

Nice, but I don't understand **why** the exception is thrown. All I did, prior to the line that throws the exception was:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI("http://www.google.com/"));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);    // actual HTTP request
```

How do I progress from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Did you try `Log.e(TAG, "Exception:", e)`?
2. Is there nothing else in the TTY near the exception?
3. Do you have the INTERNET permission?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't get to question #3 yet, but adding the 'e' as 3rd parameter, uncovered a world of information. The first line was **ERROR/TestHttpGet(821): java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com**. Hmmm... DNS problem? I know that the Emulator's built-in browser has no problem accessing google.com (or other sites). Perhaps this is indeed the INTERNET permission?

Comment: Yes, it most likely is. If you don't have the INTERNET permission, any attempt to connect to remote server will be denied. You can try going to the built-in browser and going to www.google.com. If that works, it's definitely the permission.

Comment: You were right - again! The only thing missing was the android.permission.INTERNET in the manifest file. Thank you.